# Datetimepicker bootstrap not functioning with properly with CSS bootstrap file

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using datatimepicker of bootstrap and it's working only to certain extent. It would select date fine but we be stuck at time icon if i would want to select time. If I remove `css/bootstrap.css` file then it performs just fine but then I loose all the layout. It's an obvious conflict of files, and I just wanted to know if I could fix it? Thank you very much

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Post a fiddle, atleast some code which conflicts according to you.

Comment: where did you added your jquery?

Comment: This is the order I have added, if I change it it messes up the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try chaning the order in which they occur in your HTML file? if one style-sheet is more important put that last. However if this dosn't slove your issue you have to manually fix the CSS conflicts in each file, or you might consider go to bootstrap and compose your own CSS fitting your neeeds

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've tried rearranging the links but it didnt help. I would've edited the CSS file myself, but I dont know what exactly is causing the problem.

Comment: A suggestion is to use developer tools in chrome/firebug/HTML-inspector tooling to see what CSS is affecting your elements this way you will see which CSS rules are overwriting each other.

Comment: Thank you Adrian for the suggestion!